# Bookmark a scroll position with a button that scrolls to that position when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some JavaScript shows the scroll progress using a progress bar. with that I have a bookmark button that adds an icon/button to the current progress position. What I would like to do is add to save that position using a cookie and additionally to add a link to the button that would scroll to the bookmarked position in the viewport.

So the code I have currently is;

```
// the elements indicating scroll progress for document height
(function(){
var w = $(window);
var prog = $('.progress-bar');
var progCount = $('.progress-count');

var wh, h, sHeight;

//the containing div from which the height is calculated
function setSizes() {
    wh = w.height();
    h = $('#page-content-wrapper').height();
    sHeight = h - wh;
}

setSizes();

w.on('scroll', function () {
    var perc = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, w.scrollTop() / sHeight));
    updateProgress(perc);
})

.on('resize', function () {
    setSizes();
    w.trigger('scroll');
});

//progress percentage 
function updateProgress(perc) {
    progCount.html(Math.round(perc * 100) + "%");
    prog.css({width : perc*100 + '%'});
    console.log (perc*100 + '%');
}

//bookmark function that adds an icon/button at the end of the progress bar's current position
//within the add - I have tried using jquery scrollto to get the 'perc' value as a scrollto directive
$('#bookmark').on("click", function() {
    var add = "";
    l = prog.width() - 2;
    t = 59;
    add = "<a href='#' title='$(...).scrollTo( 0, perc, {queue:true} );'><div class=\"star\" style=\" left:";
    add += l;
    add += "px; top:";
    add += t;
    add += "px;\"><span class='icon-bookmark tooltipper' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title data-original-title='Go Bookmark'></span></a></div>";
    $('.progress-bar').append(add);

});
```

}());

I hope this aptly explains what I am after.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: Or you could use `<a name="something">` for a section and then bookmark `...#something`.

Comment: The question is, when I scroll down and bookmark that position, let's say it is 50%, I would like my appended button (or bookmark) to have a link that scrolls down to 50%.

Comment: @JCOC611 - I already have section scroll to setup, what I need is to dynamically set bookmarks at user specified points, these points being at x% of the document height when adding the bookmark.